# how fix bubble sort optimization

Tags: c++, sorting

I need help with bubble sort. Is there any possibility to optimize the following code? How do you put it in one on the 'if'  to make it work? I tried it myself but I can't do it

```
void sort(person tab[] , int n)
{
    person tmp;
    for (int i = n-1; i >0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (tab[j].x < tab[j + 1].x)
            {
                tmp = tab[j];
                tab[j] = tab[j + 1];
                tab[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
            else{
                if(strcmp(tab[j].name,tab[j + 1].name) > 0){
                        tmp = tab[j];
                        tab[j] = tab[j + 1];
                        tab[j + 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever the optimization, you will still execute in `O(n^2)`, which is awfully slow for most purposes. The only way to optimize the bubble sort is to switch to another algorithm, usually in `O(n log(n))` (quicksort, heapsort, merge sort...)

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/230502/52915)

Comment: @Mast ok, point taken & comment deleted